# Asp.Net Two Local DBContexts to One Azure DBContext

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, azure, entity-framework-migrations

I have a web app that I developed through this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/introduction-and-overview

This tutorial put two DBContext (ApplicationDbContext and MyDBContext) with their respective databases with EF and Code First, I published in Azure several months ago and everything works well, both locally and in Azure. From the beginning I noticed that Azure only manages a database. In this database Azure are all the tables of the two DBContexts and as I said everything works well. I have done dozens of Migrations, only in my own WebApp tables (MyDBContext)

Now I want to add fields to a table of the AplicationDBContext, specifically to the AspNetUser table, so I modify the following code

```
public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
{
    /// My New Field
    public bool Disabled {get; set; }

    public ClaimsIdentity GenerateUserIdentity (ApplicationUserManager manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity (this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public Task <ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync (ApplicationUserManager manager)
    {
        return Task.FromResult (GenerateUserIdentity (manager));
    }
}
```

Then I implemented:

Enabled-Migrations -ContextTypeName ApplicationDbContext -MigrationsDirectory Migrations \ ApplicationDbContext

Add-Migration -ConfigurationTypeName MyWebApp.Migrations.ApplicationDbContext.Configuration "AddFldAspNetUsers"

Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName MyWebApp.Migrations.ApplicationDbContext.Configuration

Locally everything works fine, but when I publish in Azure I get the following error:

***Server Error in '/' Application.***
***The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database***

I do not know how to solve it, I need help:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced the same problem recently. The reason behind the problem you have scaffold the migration but haven't updated the Identity database tables in Azure.

Please follow the below points

- Before publishing, in publish window go to settings, there you could
  find ApplicationDbContext under Databases section.
- Give a tick to the check box Execute code first migrations(runs on
  application start) option. Try to re-publish it again. :)

Comment: That was the solution. Thanks!